# Older space movie with a half-rotten cyborg prostitute in a vending machine?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

All I can remember is that the group of main characters were running and decided to hideout in an abandoned spaceport/mining camp bar. One of them activates a cyborg prostitute "vending machine" and out comes a half-rotten cyborg prostitute.

If I somehow imagined this whole scenario, that's not a bad thing either.

Answer (score 30):

Battle Beyond the Stars, when John Boy goes to the Robert Vaughn planet. I was hoping to find a clip on youtube, no luck yet.

Edit: I'm pretty sure this is the machine.
[image]

Comment: Here it is: https://youtu.be/F80SHju6jCs?t=2535

Comment: This movie is available on Amazon Prime Video, and is included (for no additional charge) with a Prime membership at the time of this question